# How to load data asynchronously inside App.vue during startup before rendering the router-view?

Tags: vue.js

I setup a new Vue using the router project via `npm init vue@latest`. Before rendering the `router-view` I must load some data asynchronously and pass it as props to the `router-view`.

Changing the **App.vue** file to

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";

const response = await fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
const employees = await response.json();
</script>

<template>
  <router-view :employees="employees" />
</template>
```

won't render the current router view and comes up with the warning

```
[Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous>: setup function returned a promise, but no <Suspense> boundary was found in the parent component tree. A component with async setup() must be nested in a <Suspense> in order to be rendered. 
  at <App>
```

but my App.vue file does not have any parent, so I can't wrap it inside a suspense tag. But how can I fetch some data before rendering the view? ( And maybe show an error box if something failed instead )

Do I have to create an **NestedApp.vue** file, just to wrap it inside a suspense tag?

Do I have to come up with something like this?

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import { ref } from "vue";

const isLoading = ref(true);
const errorOccured = ref(false);
let employees = ref([]);

fetch("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
  .then(async response => {
    employees = await response.json();
    isLoading.value = false;
  })
  .catch(() => {
    errorOccured.value = true;
    isLoading.value = false;
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="errorOccured">
    Something failed!
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="isLoading">
    Still loading!
  </div>
  <router-view v-else :employees="employees" />
</template>
```

---

*As a sidenote what I want to do:*

The app must be started with an url hash containing base64 encoded data, which is a base url. After extracting and decoding it, I must fetch some data using this url before rendering the router-view.

So maybe there are some better places for this setup code? I thought about the main.ts file but if something fails, I could display an error alert box inside the App.vue file instead.

Comment: "Do I have to create an NestedApp.vue file, just to wrap it inside a suspense tag?" - yes. They can be called AppContainer and App, or else, but any way.

Comment: You can load data in async created(), then use v-if to prevent rendering the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data in async created(), then use v-if to prevent rendering the dom. (You can show loading screen or spinner instead.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isLoaded: false,
  },
  async created() {  
    // load data (async/await)...
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000)); // wait 2 sec...
 
    this.isLoaded = true;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-if="isLoaded">Loaded! -> show data</div>
  <div v-else>Loading...</div>
</div>
```